# pop3_getResponseN2: Socket connection closed

Tags: chilkat-email

After calling TransferMail() a second time the result is null. LastErrorText is

```
ChilkatLog:   TransferMail:
    DllDate: Jun 24 2022
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.91
    UnlockPrefix: NTELES.CB1022023
    Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
    Language: .NET 4.8 / x64
    VerboseLogging: 0
    Component successfully unlocked using purchased unlock code.
    PopCmdSent: STAT
    pop3_getResponseN2: Socket connection closed.
    Failed to received remainder of POP3 multi-line response.
    matchStr: 

    Failed to get STAT response   --TransferMail
--ChilkatLog
```

I recently updated from v7.5 to 9.5 which is when this issues started to appear. Was there a breaking change? What is the best way to correct this? Should the MailMan object be tossed away and re-created for every call to check for email?

Answer (score 0):

Examine the contents of the mailman.Pop3SessionLog property prior to calling TransferMail.
Maybe something happened beforehand that caused the problem.

Also, when debugging it's best to turn on VerboseLogging.   Set mailman.VerboseLogging = true

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did both of these things and still no clues. I'm adding additional logging to the app to try to track this down. It came after updating .NET Framework from 3.5 to 4.8 and then upgrading Chilkat to the latest. It may have something to do with the .NET Framework update and not Chilkat.

Comment: It turns out there was a bug in the Chilkat library. They gave me a preview build that fixed the issue. I assume it's fixed in later versions as well.